# How to display HTML in Grails Error Messages without losing encoding for User supplied content?

Tags: html, validation, grails

I need to display some HTML in Grails Error Messages, to mark some content for an external System I cannot influence. Its just some simple span tags, with a class="notranslate" attribute. By default, the HTML will get escaped, so I disabled the codec in the  tag, which leads to another problem:

Now everything the User enters will be displayed in the HTML of the Page, which enables easy XSS...
My solution for now is to only disable the HTML Codec for this Page, and use custom error messages, that do not include what the user entered, but that seems rather clumsy to me.

I also saw that there might be the possibility to fiddle around with the MessageSource, but I do not like to change to much in the bowels of Grails. Another Idea I had was to create a custom Filter, that lets only the HTML I approve of through. I also discarded this idea, it felt like I was handling the problem on the wrong abstraction level.

Any Idea how to solve this problem?

TL;DR
I need to wrap variable parts of the error message in  tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order not to get an HTML encoded error flash message, one can use the following:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${editingInstance}">
    <div class="errors">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${editingInstance}" codec="none"/>
    </div>
</g:hasErrors>
```

The 'codec' attribute will be used in ValidationTagLib.groovy:

```
Closure renderErrors = { attrs, body ->
    def renderAs = attrs.remove('as')
    if (!renderAs) renderAs = 'list'

    if (renderAs == 'list') {
        def codec = attrs.codec ?: 'HTML'
        if (codec == 'none') codec = ''

        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea with a taglib wrapper. Start with this:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${user}">
  <ul>
   <g:eachError var="err" bean="${user}">
       <li><g:message error="${err}" /></li> 
   </g:eachError>
  </ul>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Then in messages.properties create messages with some special wildcards, like this:

```
user.username.size.toosmall=Username you provided @@@{0}@@@ is too small.
```

Three ampersands is a wildard. Then create a taglib that wraps `g:message` like this:

```
class MyTagLib {
    def spanErrorMessage = { attrs, body ->
        out << message(error: attrs.error).replaceAll(/@@@.*@@@/, "<span class='notranslate'>\\1</span>")
    }
}
```

It replaces everything between `@@@` and `@@@` with a span you need. Note that these `@@@` are not escaped in HTML. Use this taglib like this:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${user}">
  <ul>
   <g:eachError var="err" bean="${user}">
       <li><g:spanErrorMessage error="${err}" /></li> 
   </g:eachError>
  </ul>
</g:hasErrors>
```

This code is untested, out of the head, so it can miss some details in regular expression, but I hope you get the idea.